# Exception: could not open socket on pyspark

Tags: sockets, apache-spark, pyspark

Whenever I am trying to execute a simple processing in pyspark, it fails to open the socket.

```
>>> myRDD = sc.parallelize(range(6), 3)
>>> sc.runJob(myRDD, lambda part: [x * x for x in part])
```

Above throws exception -

```
port 53554 , proto 6 , sa ('127.0.0.1', 53554)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/work/bigdata/spark-custom/python/pyspark/context.py", line 917, in runJob
    return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
  File "/Volumes/work/bigdata/spark-custom/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 143, in _load_from_socket
    raise Exception("could not open socket")
Exception: could not open socket

>>> 15/08/30 19:03:05 ERROR PythonRDD: Error while sending iterator
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:404)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$2.run(PythonRDD.scala:613)
```

I checked through rdd.py _load_from_socket and realised it gets the port , but the server is not even started or sp runJob might be the issue-

```
port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not the ideal solution but now I am aware of the cause.
Pyspark is unable to create jvm socket with JDK 1.8 (64-bit) version, so I just set my java path to jdk 1.7 and it worked.

Comment: It does not work for me. I use Spark 1.5.2 and jdk1.7 version.

Comment: The error is when the python driver tries to connect to the scala part of the driver, on any spark action(count, reduce....) 

The corresponding line below shows that the timeout is hardcoded to be 3 seconds. 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L121

Technically there is no way right now to configure the timeout, therefore the only way for python code to recover is to catch the exception in application-level code and retry for a configurable number of times.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the exact same error, tried JDK 1.7 and it didn't work, then i went and edited the /etc/hosts file and realized i had the following lines

```
127.0.0.1 mbp.local localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Just commented out the line with my computer local name and it worked.

```
#127.0.0.1 mbp.local localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Tested on PySpark 1.6.3 and 2.0.2 with JDK 1.8

Comment: This worked..Saved my life while debugging Spark Cluster in production!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my problem.

when I started pyspark, I suddenly realized there was a warning which might have a connection with the issue.

*WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, localhost resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 172.16.20.244 instead (on interface en0)
2020-09-27 17:26:10 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address*

Then I made a change  of /etc/hosts, commenting 127.0.0.1 and adding a new line to solve the loopback problem, like this,

```
#127.0.0.1  localhost
#255.255.255.255    broadcasthost
#:::1             localhost
172.16.20.244 localhost
```

It worked.

I hope it could help those have a lot of pains solving this problem with the similar warnings.